# Standard (legal?) phrase for a clear mind

Tags: phrase-requests, legalese

Is there a standard (possibly legal) phrase to denote that a person has a clear mind and is capable of doing things well and understanding the consequences of their actions (as opposed to being e.g. drunk, high or sedated)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the phrase "being of sound mind" which is often seen in a legal context.
One lawyer discusses the phrase in [this page](https://www.larcomes.co.uk/law-define-sound-mind/).

The Oxford Dictionaries has the following definition in its lengthy entry for [**sound**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sound), as the first meaning of the adjective.

> **sound**
>   ADJECTIVE
>   **1** In good condition; not damaged, injured, or diseased.
>   *he was not of sound mind*